# How to add a number of records into a List<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, c#-4.0

I have created an asp.net application using Entity Framework. In this I want to add the records into a list. For this I have to use the foreach loop but it always adding only last record data for all records, meaning it's showing same data. Here I have pasted my code. Please verify it once and guide where I can change.

```
     public List<CategoryItems> ListMenuCategory(int MenuId)
    {
        string str = string.Empty;
        string strJSON = string.Empty;
        List<CategoryItems> resultmenu;
        resultmenu = new List<CategoryItems>();
        List<CategoryItems> Result;
        Result = new List<CategoryItems>();
        bool check = true;
        var objmenuCategory = from cat in objEntity.menucategories where cat.MenuId == MenuId && cat.Active == check select cat;
        CategoryItems Categorylist = new CategoryItems();
        foreach (menucategory category in objmenuCategory)
        {
            Categorylist.CategoryName = category.CategoryName;
            Categorylist.Description = category.Description;
            int menuid = category.MenuCategoryId;
            List<menuitem> menuitems = GetMenucategories(menuid);
            foreach (var items in menuitems)
            {
                Categorylist.ItemName = items.ItemName;
                Categorylist.Description = items.Description;
                Categorylist.Price = (float)items.Price;
                string Image = items.Picture;
                Categorylist.Picture = "http://restaurantmanager.testshell.net/Images/" + Image;
                Categorylist.Thumbnail = "http://restaurantmanager.testshell.net/Images/" + items.Thumbnail;
                if (items.CreatedDate != null)
                {
                    Categorylist.CreatedDate = (DateTime)items.CreatedDate;
                }

                if (items.ModifiedDate != null)
                {
                    Categorylist.ModifiedDate = (DateTime)items.ModifiedDate;
                }
                Result.Add(Categorylist);

            }


            // Result.AddRange(menus);


        }
        return Result;



        }


    private List<menuitem> GetMenucategories(int p)
       {
        restaurantEntities objEntity1 = new restaurantEntities();
         var menuitems = from items in objEntity1.menuitems where items.MenuCategoryId == p select items;
   return menuitems.ToList();
     }
```

Comment: As this isn't about `ArrayList` at all, but `List<T>`, I changed that in the question.

Comment: Thank you Guff u r  right that List<T>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the `Categorylist` item outside of the loops, so you are only using one single item, filling it with different data and adding it over and over to the result.

You have to create the item inside the innermost loop, so that each iteration gets its own object.

---

Note: ChrisF also spotted that you call `AddRange` inside the loop, which has the result that you will add the same set of items over and over. You don't need to call `AddRange` at all, you can just skip the `Result` list entirely and just return `resultmenu` instead.

Comment: Hi thank you for giving response actually i want retunr the data in a sigle list like json format iwant display the data like <categoryitem><itemes>....</items><items>...</items></categoryitem>

Comment: But it showing like <categoryitem><items>...</items></categoryitem><categoryitem><items>...</items></categoryitem> this was showing when i using the item object in to innerloop ....

Comment: @Victor: Then you have to change your objects so that the `CategoryItem` class contains an `Items` collection, not a single item. Then you can create a single `CategoryItem` object and add items to its `Item` collection.

Comment: Hi,i have get the child table using category id and assign that items to the categoryitems collection but it showing result correct if only one record exist in child table,if more than one record it anothe list items not in same list ...

Comment: @Victor: Yes, that is because you have a list of `CategoryItem` each containing one item instead of one `CategoryItem` containing a list of items.

Comment: actually my requirement is <categories><category1><items><item1></item1>....<item2></item2>....</items></category1><category2><items><item1>....</item1><item2>...</item2></items></category2></categories>

Comment: @Victor: For that you have to serialise it yourself. If you serialise a list, the elements won't be named like `category1`, `category2`. Besides, that is not common practive for XML documents either.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3317/discussion-between-victor-and-guffa)